# Django Change inherited form meta class

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to edit the `Meta Class` of a form that inherits its data from a `ModelForm`. All I want is to add one field, I don't want to repeat all the form.

```
# NuevaBibliotecaCompartida is a ModelForm

class EditarBibliotecaCompartida(NuevaBibliotecaCompartida):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('nombre', 'direccion', 'imagen', 'punto_google_maps')
```

I get the error `ModelForm has no model class specified`, of course, because I am overriding the Meta class when I add a field. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to explicitly subclass the parent's `Meta` class:

```
class Meta(NuevaBibliotecaCompartida.Meta):
    # `model` will now be inherited
    fields = ('nombre', 'direccion', 'imagen', 'punto_google_maps')
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple direct answer.

Comment: Does not work, throws an attribute error on Meta of superclass

Answer (score 14):

if you do not want to type the fields of the parent form class you can also get them with the *ParentClass.Meta.fields*:

```
class Meta(NuevaBiblioteca.Meta):
    fields = NuevaBiblioteca.Meta.fields + ('YourAddedFormField',)
```