# Override Django Forms's Meta Classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, metaclass, django-3.0

`ContactForm` is a common form in my app being used multiple times. I already have a `Foreign Key` of `Contact` Model in `Guardian` table.So the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996451/save-new-foreign-key-with-django-form) from the solution works for me.

But its making bit complex to write entire form again for below `ContactForm` fields when I have to reuse. So kept `ContactForm` separate to make it reusable.

But still sometimes few fields are optional from the `ContactForm`, so not able to reuse same `ContactForm` again.

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ("address", "city", "district", "state", "country", 
                 "pincode", "phone1", "phone2", "is_emergency")
```

Ex. From above `ContactForm`, I want to use only `phone1`, `phone2` and `is_emergency` flag in the `GuardianForm`.
Is there anyway to override `Meta` class by inheriting `ContactForm` in to the `GuardianForm` such as:

```
class GuardianForm(forms.ModelForm, ContactForm): #obviously this will not work
  first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, label = "First Name")
  last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, label = "Last Name")
  # Other Fields ...

  class Meta:
    model = Guardian
    fields = ('passport_number', 'pan_number', 'annual_income',
        'phone1', 'phone2', 'is_emergency',)  # Only 3 Fields of `ContactForm`
```

OR - Is there any standard better approach to overcome this issue?

Comment: I don't understand the comment, *".. Only 3 Fields of `ContactForm"* Can you explain what do you mean by this?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu - I have to use only those 3 fields (`phone1`, `phone2` & `is_emergency`) from `ContactForm`  to the `GuardianForm`.

Comment: This links may helpful
1.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance
2.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534950/django-change-inherited-form-meta-class

Comment: @RiyasAc - It makes more sens to me.Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achive, but here is how you can extend Django Forms's Meta Class :

```py
class GuardianForm(ContactForm): 
    class Meta(ContactForm.Meta):
        fields = ("phone1", "phone2", "is_emergency")
```